# help understanding typedef struct

Tags: c, objective-c

i come from a php background and am studying this page http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000081.php before i step foot into some of the harder stuff in regards to objective-c

if i type something like this

```
typedef struct { 
int lengthInSeconds; 
int yearRecorded; 
} Song;
```

and when setting a function or a variable of type Song, what does it mean? i understand that by setting a function as an int or maybe a float the output would be related to its type set. but when i do something like this

```
Song myvariable;
or
Song myfunction(int params) { }

what type is Song setting?
```

thanks

Answer (score 15):

I think it would help you the most to know just what is going on in the compiler's head.  Using your example:

```
typedef struct { 
int lengthInSeconds; 
int yearRecorded; 
} Song;
```

There are actually two things happening here.  The first is that you're defining an anonymous `struct`:

```
struct { 
int lengthInSeconds; 
int yearRecorded; 
}
```

This anonymous `struct` can be used anywhere a type (e.g. `int` or `const char*`) could be used.  The following example is actually valid, though nobody should ever write code like this because it's a maintenance nightmare:

```
struct { 
int lengthInSeconds; 
int yearRecorded; 
}* GetSongInfo(const char* songName);
```

This declares a function that gets the information for a song with a given name (assuming names are unique, an invalid assumption in real life) and returns a pointer to a `struct` with its metadata.

I referred to that as an "anonymous `struct`" because the named struct form looks like this:

```
struct Song { 
int lengthInSeconds; 
int yearRecorded; 
}
```

Now you can refer to that struct by name, *but not in the fashion you would think coming from languages other than C!*  Specifically, the function above would now be declared as:

```
struct Song* GetSongInfo(const char* songName);
```

Note that the type name is `struct Song` and not just `Song`!  As a matter of fact, `struct`s have a separate namespace of their own... so *there is nothing in the language to guarantee that `struct Song` and `Song` are the same thing!*  I have no idea if Objective C maintains this insanity, but I'd bet it does to be on the safe side.

The second thing is that you're feeding that anonymous structure to `typedef`.  `typedef` simply takes one type and defines a name for it that you can use later.  So you're really saying "a `Song` is an alias for that `struct {...}` I just declared."

By `typedef`ing `Song`, you can instead write:

```
Song* GetSongInfo(const char* songName);
```

(Yes, I know it would be better to return `const Song*`, but that's beside the point.)

It may interest you to note that C has many typedefs in its standard libraries, intended to separate the particulars of a platform from the particulars of the C standard.  For example, `<unistd.h>` defines `size_t`, the integer type that represents a size (and is the return type of the built-in `sizeof()` function), and by extension, the type you should pass to functions like `malloc()`.  There is also the recent `<stdint.h>` header which defines integer types by their size in bits, e.g. `uint8_t` for an 8-bit unsigned integer.  The line in `<stdint.h>` probably looks something like:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
```

Since most platforms have 8-bit characters.  (I've programmed for some platforms like TI DSPs where a `char` was not 8-bits; usually it was 16, since the processor could not access parts of words.  But let's ignore degenerate platforms for the time being.)

Finally, to explain your examples:

```
Song myvariable;
```

This declares storage for a `Song` structure.  If it is in a function definition, that storage will be allocated on the stack and released when the function terminates.  If it is outside a function definition, it will be allocated as a global.  In either case, it will be uninitialized, which in C means it can contain any random values.  C does not keep track of uninitialized variables or set them to "uninitialized" or whatever like PHP and Python does.   C doesn't throw exceptions either.

```
Song myfunction(int params) { }
```

This defines a function that takes an integer and returns a `Song` structure.  The `return` statement for the function must be given a `Song`.  For example:

```
Song myfunction(int params)
{
    Song result;
    result.lengthInSeconds = GetSongLength(params); 
    result.yearRecorded = GetSongYear(params); 
    return result;
}
```

This function allocates space on the stack for a `Song`, fills in its fields by calling functions that return `int`s, then `return` copies the structure `result` into the space reserved for the return value, and finally the storage for `result` is released when the function ends.  Usually, the compiler can optimize away the copy implicit in the `return` statement.  Also, there may be another (possibly optimized) copy from the return value storage to a final destination, for example when you say:

```
Song foundSongInfo = myfunction(params);
```

By the way, returning `struct`s on the stack is frowned upon, since compilers can usually optimize better if the return value fits in a register (i.e. is a simple type).  (There are exceptions in C++ with operator overloading, but that's off-topic.)  A better definition would be:

```
void myfunction(int params, Song* found)
{
    found->lengthInSeconds = GetSongLength(params); 
    found->yearRecorded = GetSongYear(params); 
}
```

This avoids all the extra copies.  You call it like so:

```
Song foundSongInfo;
myfunction(params, &foundSongInfo);
```

This is one case where two lines can be faster than one.

I may have missed some things, let me know if this makes sense...

Comment: One of the best answers I've ever seen on StackOverflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that Objective C is very close to C, you do this:

```
Song myvariable; // creates the truct in memory
myvariable.lengthInSeconds = 10;
myvariable.yearRecorded = 2010;
```

I cannot say what the function does because you have not given its impl.

Here is how you fix the function to do something "useful":

```
Song myfunction(int params) { 
  Song ret;
  ret.lengthInseconds = params * 69;
  ret.yearRecorded = 3*5*7*9*11;
  return ret;
}
```

(Jut to illustrate that the function can do whatever ...

Answer (score 2):

In the first case:

```
Song myvariable;
```

You're declaring myvariable to be an instance of the struct you declared in your typedef.

In the second case:

```
Song myfunction(int params) { }
```

You're declaring a function that takes one integer, and returns a Song.  Since there's no code in the curly braces, you're not actually returning anything, and the compiler would report an error in your code.

Comment: I would just add that the first means "Reserve enough memory space to hold a structure of type Song and call it myvariable" while the second is: "I promise that this function will return a structure of type Song".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a wikipedia article on C's structs.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29

Comment: i read the article on wikipedia. but dont understand its purpose, would it be similar to writing classes in php?

Comment: Structs are similar to classes in that they group up several other variables (in this case, two ints) into a self-contained packet of data (see other answers by NSResponder and lpthnc). The ideologies of a C struct and a PHP class are rather different, though.